# How to generate JAVA Artifacts from WSDL?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

We have requirement for Contract First Web services for one of my Project.
We have defined the WSDL file so I need to generate Java Artifacts from WSDL with JAX-WS,
So Is there any way so that I can generate the Java Server side form exposing the WSDL.

Thanks,
Ramakrishna Rayudu

Comment: JAX-WS is a specification. Use real implementation, e.g. [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). [This page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) will show you how to convert your WSDL to Java artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663420/how-to-call-a-web-service-using-javaee/9693919#9693919).
It explains how to generate the Metro-JAX-WS-Stubs (artifacts) from a given WSDL using the `wsimport`-Tool shipped with your JDK.

Hope this helpes! Have fun!

**EDIT:**
Sorry I missunderstood your question!

Apache AXIS ships with a function called *wsd2java*. That could be helpful in your case.
Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179229/generating-web-service-from-wsdl-file), giving links to tutorials for different IDEs.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for you response.But I need to Generate The Server side Java Artifacts It seems to be on the client side can you just verify that post ones.

Answer (score 0):

use

xjc -wsdl <wsdlurl> -d <directory>

xjc tool can be found inside C:\Program Files\jaxb